# Get the Attachment ID from an Image URL in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, media, attachment

I recently needed a way to get the ID of a WordPress image attachment, but I only had the image URL to work with. The problem was complicated by the fact that the image URL could be a thumbnail of the original image attachment, i.e. one of the auto-generated post thumbnail image sizes.

Answer (score 9):

I know this old but there's a quick solution for this. Use [attachment_url_to_postid](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/attachment_url_to_postid/) WordPress function.

Example usage:

```
echo attachment_url_to_postid( 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/image-abc.png' );
```

Output:

```
45
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find or make a regex for removing the dimensions from resized versions of image attachments, but here's how you can get the ID of any given attachment URL. Pippin Williamson wrote a brief function for querying the database:

https://pippinsplugins.com/retrieve-attachment-id-from-image-url/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, its not working in my case because of image upload using gravityform and its not using WP upload function.